# Converting RTL doc to PDF

Tags: php, right-to-left, phpword

Is there any way to read from RTL doc/docx file and converting to PDF format with the same style? the result of my code is just a part of my document without images and header and footer section.

```
// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('doc2.docx');

$lang    = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Language();
$lang->setLangId(1065);
$phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang($lang);

// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setRTL(true);
$fontStyle->setName('B nazanin');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$phpWord->addFontStyle('*', $fontStyle);

// I plan to get PDF version after converting HTML
// but it does not read all content from the word file

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('doc.html');
```